# Confused syntax in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

what does the line (rowid,0) mean in the following query

```
select * from emp 
WHERE (ROWID,0) in (
    select rowid, mod(rownum,2) from emp
);
```

i dont get the line `WHERE (ROWID,0)`.

what is it?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` clause in Oracle SQL can support column groups. You can do things like this:

```
select ...
  from tab1
 where (tab1.col1, tab1.col2) in (
    select tab2.refcol1, tab2.refcol2
      from tab2
 )
```

That can be useful in many cases.

In your particular case, the subquery use for the second expression `mod(rownum,2)`. Since there is no order by, that means that `rownum` will be in whichever order the database retrieves the rows - that might be a full table scan or a fast full index scan.

Then by using `mod` every other row in the subquery gets the value 0, every other row gets the value 1.

The `IN` clause then filters on second value in the subquery being equal to 0. The end result is that this query retrieves *half* of your employees. Which half will depend on which access path the optimizer chooses.

Comment: Looks like an interesting (but slow) method for getting a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what dialect of sql you're using, but it appears that since the subquery in the IN clause has two columns in the select list, then the (ROWID,0) indicates which columns align with the subquery. I have never seen multiple columns in an IN statment's select list before.

Comment: An expression `where (a,b) in (select x,y ...)` is defined in the SQL standard and is supported by several DBMS (for example: Oracle, Postgres, DB2)

Comment: thanks, never used it, always used exists in those cases I guess

Comment: This can be extended to more situations. e.g.: `where (a,b) <> ( (1,2) )` or even `where (t1.a, t1.b) <> (t2.x, t2.y)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax used by some databases (but not all) that allows you to do `in` with multiple values.

With `in`, this is the same as:

```
where exists (select 1
              from emp e2
              where e2.rowid = emp.rowid and
                    mod(rownum, 2) = 0
             )
```

I should note that if you are using Oracle (which allows this syntax), then you are using `rownum` in a subquery with no `order by`.  The results are going to be rather arbitrary.  However, the intention seems to be to return every other row, in some sense.